# C - Division returns zero

Tags: c

Working on an assignment where the user inputs an int and then 1 to get the square, 2 for cube, and 3 to divide in by two. Can't figure out why my shrink function always returns zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Function prototypes
int Square(int value);
int Cube(int value);
double Shrink(int value);

int main ()
{
    /* variable definition: */
    int intValue, menuSelect,Results;
    intValue = 1;
    // While a positive number
    while (intValue > 0)
    {
        printf ("Enter a positive Integer\n: ");
        scanf("%d", &intValue);
        if (intValue > 0)
        {
            printf ("Enter 1 to calculate Square, 2 to Calculate Cube, 3 to divide     integer in half \n: ");
            scanf("%d", &menuSelect);

            if (menuSelect == 3)
            {
                // Call the shrink function

                Results = Shrink(intValue);
                printf("Half of %d is %lf\n",intValue,Results);
            }
            else
                printf("Invalid menu item, only 1,2 or 3 is accepted\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/* function returning half of a number */
double Shrink(int value)
{
    return (double) value/2.0;
}
```

Comment: You print `intValue` and `Results` which are *uninitialised  variables*. Not only that, the statements are not inside a function, so will not compile. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Re the code now posted: I get 2 errors and 2 warnings from compiler.

Comment: sorry I'm having issues posting all of the code, its saying my post has too much code. Let me update it again

Comment: Re the latest code edit, in `printf("Half of %d is %lf\n",intValue,Results);` you are passing `int` to a `double` format. Please enable all compiler warnings, there is still another warning.

Comment: Thanks! fixed my code and now its running as it should. For some reason ideone wasn't giving me any warnings. Apologies for the first two edits leaving out relevant information.

Comment: Get your own compiler and compile locally, they are free. Those sites are no use for program development, only for demonstration of working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int intValue, menuSelect,Results;`

So `Results` is declared as `int`.

When you assign it to your function result, it gets rounded/truncated (probably not what you want, but only part of the issue).

The fact that `0.0` is printed is because you're using `%lf` format in `printf`, which doesn't match `int` data type, and no conversion is performed here, since `printf` uses variable arguments and trusts the caller (some compilers issue warnings though).

Quickfix:

```
double Results;
```

should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

First, your program does have errors.
Anyway, to answer your question, your `Shrink()` function does return the half of a number ; the problem is you save it in an `int` variable, who cannot take `float` numbers. (Only the numbers before the decimal point will be taken).
You have two options : you can declare `Results` as a `float` or `double`, or print directly the result of your function as following :

```
printf("%lf", Shrink(intValue));
```